# Unable to bind data from JSON to Model Class

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a spring Boot application in which I'm using Restful Api and sending data in JSON Format through POSTMAN. I want that data to map with my model class, i.e Request data class, but I'm getting null values.

main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ContactApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ContactGEApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller Class- this one is controller class. In this class we will map the url with /rfs
    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@RestController
public class ContactController {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ContactController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rfs", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ServiceResponse<String> serviceRequest(@RequestBody RequestData requestData) throws JsonProcessingException {

        System.out.println(requestData);
        System.out.println("M in controller");
        return ServiceResponse.success();

    }
}
```

Request Data.java- this one is my model class. In this I'm defining all the fields and getters and setters

```
public class RequestData {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String EquipmentID;
    private String Modality;
    private String FacilityID;
    private String CountryCode;
    private String ISOCode;
    private String ProblemType;
    private String ProblemArea;
    private String EquipmentStatus;
    private String Name;
    private String PhoneNumber;
    private String Extension;
    private String Description;
    private String ShortDescription;
    private String TimePeriod;
    private String ServiceCode;
    private String Locale;
    private String RequestingApp;
    private String ExamNumber;
    private String SeriesNumber;
    private String ImageNumber;

    public String getEquipmentID() {
        return EquipmentID;
    }

    public void setEquipmentID(String equipmentID) {
        EquipmentID = equipmentID;
    }

    public String getModality() {
        return Modality;
    }

    public void setModality(String modality) {
        Modality = modality;
    }

    public String getFacilityID() {
        return FacilityID;
    }

    public void setFacilityID(String facilityID) {
        FacilityID = facilityID;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return CountryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        CountryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getISOCode() {
        return ISOCode;
    }

    public void setISOCode(String iSOCode) {
        ISOCode = iSOCode;
    }

    public String getProblemType() {
        return ProblemType;
    }

    public void setProblemType(String problemType) {
        ProblemType = problemType;
    }

    public String getProblemArea() {
        return ProblemArea;
    }

    public void setProblemArea(String problemArea) {
        ProblemArea = problemArea;
    }

    public String getEquipmentStatus() {
        return EquipmentStatus;
    }

    public void setEquipmentStatus(String equipmentStatus) {
        EquipmentStatus = equipmentStatus;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return PhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return Extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        Extension = extension;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return ShortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        ShortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public String getTimePeriod() {
        return TimePeriod;
    }

    public void setTimePeriod(String timePeriod) {
        TimePeriod = timePeriod;
    }

    public String getServiceCode() {
        return ServiceCode;
    }

    public void setServiceCode(String serviceCode) {
        ServiceCode = serviceCode;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return Locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        Locale = locale;
    }

    public String getRequestingApp() {
        return RequestingApp;
    }

    public void setRequestingApp(String requestingApp) {
        RequestingApp = requestingApp;
    }

    public String getExamNumber() {
        return ExamNumber;
    }

    public void setExamNumber(String examNumber) {
        ExamNumber = examNumber;
    }

    public String getSeriesNumber() {
        return SeriesNumber;
    }

    public void setSeriesNumber(String seriesNumber) {
        SeriesNumber = seriesNumber;
    }

    public String getImageNumber() {
        return ImageNumber;
    }

    public void setImageNumber(String imageNumber) {
        ImageNumber = imageNumber;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RequestData [EquipmentID=" + EquipmentID + ", Modality=" + Modality + ", FacilityID=" + FacilityID
                + ", CountryCode=" + CountryCode + ", ISOCode=" + ISOCode + ", ProblemType=" + ProblemType
                + ", ProblemArea=" + ProblemArea + ", EquipmentStatus=" + EquipmentStatus + ", Name=" + Name
                + ", PhoneNumber=" + PhoneNumber + ", Extension=" + Extension + ", Description=" + Description
                + ", ShortDescription=" + ShortDescription + ", TimePeriod=" + TimePeriod + ", ServiceCode="
                + ServiceCode + ", Locale=" + Locale + ", RequestingApp=" + RequestingApp + ", ExamNumber=" + ExamNumber
                + ", SeriesNumber=" + SeriesNumber + ", ImageNumber=" + ImageNumber + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Header : `Content-Type:application/json` added ? also add input, request URL as they are the source of debug points

Comment: Hi vinay still its not binding values from JSON to POJO class RequestData . RequestData  fields are still null

Comment: What JSON are you actually sending?

Comment: Pleasd attach input json that you trying witb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the fields in RequestData are all capitalized. This seems to cause a problem with the getters and the deserializer.  If you change the fields to begin with a lower case letter, and in your JSON request use the matching lowercase fields, it will populate RequestData.

Comment: if i am sending json with frst letter in lower case its working fine and mapping the data as well as thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

Add @ResponseBody before your method in Rest

```
@RestController
public class ContactGEController {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ContactGEController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rfs", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
    public ServiceResponse<String> serviceRequest(@RequestBody RequestData requestData) throws JsonProcessingException {

        System.out.println(requestData);
        System.out.println("M in controller");
        return ServiceResponse.success();

    }
}
```